# How to add layout with red background color when Swiping to Delete in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have a recyclerview which has a swipeToDeleteHandler:

```
private fun swipeToDeleteHandler() {
    simpleItemTouchCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
        0,
        ItemTouchHelper.LEFT
    ) {

        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "on Move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return true
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, swipeDir: Int) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Removed! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            //Remove swiped item from list and notify the RecyclerView
            deleteRowFromDb(viewHolder.adapterPosition + 1)
            //adapter.notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

Which deletes from my SQLi db the row that the user swiped. The problem is, **what is the most efficient way to add a red background with an trash icon while the user is swiping to delete the row**? It is seen in most apps nowadays.

Comment: edit the individual list items layout to include the view that you want (red background with trash icon) and make sure it fits behind your current list items. Every time the onSwiped is called make that view visible, otherwise, set its visibility again to Invisible/Gone.

Comment: Follow these two links , its helps you https://github.com/kitek/android-rv-swipe-delete
https://github.com/agilie/SwipeToDelete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need to do its just delete element on swipe the easiest way is to draw it on ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback

```
override fun onChildDraw(canvas, recyclerView, viewHolder, ..) {
    val itemView = viewHolder.itemView
    val itemHeight = itemView.bottom - itemView.top

    // Draw the red delete background
    background.color = backgroundColor
    background.setBounds(
            itemView.right + dX.toInt(),
            itemView.top,
            itemView.right,
            itemView.bottom
    )
    background.draw(canvas)

    // Calculate position of delete icon
    val iconTop = itemView.top + (itemHeight - inHeight) / 2
    val iconMargin = (itemHeight - inHeight) / 2
    val iconLeft = itemView.right - iconMargin - inWidth
    val iconRight = itemView.right - iconMargin
    val iconBottom = iconTop + inHeight

    // Draw the delete icon
    icon.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom)
    icon.draw(canvas)

    super.onChildDraw(canvas, recyclerView, viewHolder, ...)
}
```

[Original topic](https://medium.com/@kitek/recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-easier-than-you-thought-cff67ff5e5f6)

But if you need more than just remove item on swipe, for example, you need two buttons like "Delete" and "Edit" you can use 3rd party libraries like [This One](https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout)

Answer (score 0):

- I found the medium article, [HERE](https://medium.com/@acerezoluna/part-3-recyclerview-from-zero-to-hero-397b7996280), to help with this
- However, the tutorial is a little confusing, so I would recommend just looking at the person's source code. Which can be found [HERE](https://github.com/Jachu5/recycler/blob/1592a6c5b2ce9b8c28642b88333f33d5f50c0752/app/src/main/java/com/unchained/itemtouchexample/SwipeBackgroundHelper.kt)
- If you don't like when the red background appears, increase the `threshold` value found inside the companion object:

```
 companion object {
        //INCREASE the value to make the red background appear sooner

        private const val THRESHOLD = 2.5

        //DECREASE the value to make the red background appear later
}
```